# Add space between type and diamond bracket, and after comma

Tags: visual-studio-2013, autocomplete, ide

I'm using Visual Studio 2013. I've got all my formatting perfect (which is none whatsoever) except for when I do

```
Dictionary <int, int> dict = new
```

and I hit enter for the autocomplete it'll end up as

```
Dictionary <int, int> dict = new Dictionary<int,int> ();
```

I want it to instead be

```
Dictionary <int, int> dict = new Dictionary <int, int> ();
                                           ^     ^
```

Notice the extra space marked by the `^`. Going back and adding those 2 extra spaces is really hurting productivity!

The same thing occurs when I use generics with a single type such as `List <int>`. I looked at every formatting option in the settings and I don't see anything about this one.